# Theming logo and site name

Tags: 7, theming

I am using [Corporate Clean](https://www.drupal.org/project/corporateclean) theme and I want to make some changes to how the logo and site name are displayed. What file would do that in? Sorry, newbie here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find **page.tpl.php** file in theme's root folder (`sites/all/themes/corporateclean/page.tpl.php`).

You'll see that this file defines how and where variables and regions get printed. You can make changes right there.

What you're looking for is **$logo** and **$site_name** variables.